# Calculating proximity Near tool with XY data in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, tools, proximity

I am trying to calculate the nearest distance from a set of lat/long coordinates to a database that contains a list of library addresses. I have managed to import the lat/long coordinates and exported them to a .shp file. Now when I run the Near tool, I am confused as to what the output means. What is NEAR_FID and in what unit is NEAR_Distance if the input was in xy data and the output used BIN,BBL numbers?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the **[help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000)** on the Near Analysis tool.

As described in the help:

NEAR_FID is:

> The Object ID of the closest near feature.

And NEAR_Distance is:

> The value is in the linear unit of the input features coordinate
>   system, or Meters when the Method parameter is set to GEODESIC and the
>   input is in a geographic coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000

NEAR_FID
The Object ID of the closest near feature.

NEAR_DIST
The distance between the input and near feature. The value is in the linear unit of the input features coordinate system, or Meters when the Method parameter is set to GEODESIC and the input is in a geographic coordinate system.

NEAR_FC 
The catalog path to the feature class that contains the near feature. This field is only added to the output table if multiple Near Features are specified.